# Shell variable visible in double quoted Perl one-liner

Tags: perl, shell

I understand shell variables are local to the current shell while environment variables (the `export`ed ones) are passed onto child processes forked by the shell.

When I run a Perl one-liner within double quotes I can access the (local) shell variable from the `fork`ed perl process:

```
$ FOO=bar
$ perl -we "print qx'echo $FOO'"
bar
```

Why is that?

Comment: Compare to: `perl -we 'print qx/ echo $ENV{FOO} /'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because of shell variable interpolation in double-quoted strings.

The `$FOO` variable is evaluated in the parent shell - in which `$FOO` has value `bar` - and interpolated into the quoted string.

Therefore the perl code you are actually running is:

```
print qx'echo bar'
```

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash) is a more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 4):

This is because your shell translates the content of `$FOO` before it is submitted to Perl.

If you want to use this `$FOO` from your Perl environment, do this:

```
perl -we "print qx'echo \$FOO'"
```

The shell should translate `\$` in to `$` before passing it away.

Comment: Another way is to use single quotes for the inline Perl code: `perl -we 'print qx'\''echo $FOO'\'''`.